# Having Access To Ui of another class

Tags: qt

I have a class named FirstPage
And I have An Object of FirstPage in the mainwindow !
now I want to have access to the "Ui" Of the FirstPage in the mainwindow
But I can't !

```
    namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:

private:
    FirstPage* FrstPg;
};

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    FrstPg = new FirstPage (this);
    connect (FrstPg->ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked(),FrstPg,SLOT(show());//Error ERRor
}
```

what should I do ?!

Answer (score 0):

Why did you forward declare a `MainWindow` class in your `Ui` namespace but your `MainWindow` declaration isn't in this namespace? You end up having two different `MainWindow` classes, one in the global namespace and one in the `Ui` namespace. I think what you're trying to do is that:

```
namespace Ui {

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:

private:
    FirstPage* FrstPg;
};

}
```

And same for the cpp file:

```
namespace Ui {

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    FrstPg = new FirstPage (this);
    connect (FrstPg->ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked(),FrstPg,SLOT(show());//Error ERRor
}

}
```

Now regarding your error, why do you try to do the connect here in your `MainWindow` class and not in your `FirstPage` class? Both your signal and your slot are in this class, I don't see any reason to do the connect here. Is there something I missed?

Comment: I did change the name Of the Ui of the FirstPage ! But it Still douesn't work
connect (FrstPg->firstpage_ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),FrstPg,SLOT(show());

Comment: What do you want to do with that connect? It seems that you want to show the `FirstPage` widget when the user clicks that push button. But if the button is inside the FirstPage, it will never be shown... Can you be a bit more explicit on what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes I want To do exactly what You said ! but I don't have that problme because it is shown in the first time with this Part in my mainWindow constructor! ::    FrstPg = new FirstPage (this);

Comment: Then I think you should move your button to your `MainWindow`. You can set the `visible` property on your FirstPage to hide it by default.

Answer (score 0):

To gain access to FirstPage's `ui` ivar move `Ui::FirstPage *ui;` from `private` to `public` section in FirstPage.h

P.S. Uflex's suggestion about namespace is incorrect: `namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }` is used for forward declaration of `Ui::MainWindow *ui;` in MainWindow.h